# How can I display multiple inline suggestions in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a plugin for vscode that suggests lines of code to developers.

My issue is that I can't show multiple suggestions at the same time. For example, the plugin may need to show "statement 1" in line 13 of the file, and "statement 2" in line 16.

These suggestions should not be inserted directly in the code, since the developer is choosing if they want to keep them or not. Basically, I am searching for a suggestion metodology similar to GitHub Copilot, where different lines in different points of the code are shown in a grey color.

I currently tried to use the "InlineCompletionItem" interface from the vscode API. I can successfully show 1 suggestion in the desired position, and accept/reject it.

I use "registerInlineCompletionItemProvider" to register my implementation of the "provideInlineCompletionItems" interface, in which I create a list of "InlineCompletionItems"
and return it. I then trigger it with

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.inlineSuggest.trigger');
```

When triggered, only the first element of such list is displayed.

I know of the existence of "CompletionItem" and "CompletionList", but they work by showing suggestions in a drop down menu near the cursor, which is not what I need.

Is there someone that has tried to do something similar, and succeeded?

Comment: maybe abuse decorations and roll your own UI for prev/next?

Comment: use decorations and insert text `before` or `after` the positions you want

Answer (score 0):

At the time of this writing, I don't think VS Code's inline completions API supports this. [`InlineCompletionItemProvider`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InlineCompletionItemProvider) returns a [`InlineCompletionList`](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#InlineCompletionList), but as you said, those are "disjoint" options, and only one can be selected by the user.

You could consider not using the inline completion API at all and instead abuse the text editor decoration API to roll your own UI for inline previews, and create your own commands and keybindings for "accepting" those completions. You could look at abusing code lenses for your prev/next buttons (and also the accept button) if your "completion provider" provides multiple options at a time.

You might also be interested in issue ticket [Inline suggestions aren't multicursor aware #146041](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146041), but that'd presumably require your users to manually create cursors where the insertion points should go.

Another option is to [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md) asking for exactly what you want.